# Android 4.2.2 slide screen after unlock the app - programmatically

Tags: android, user-interface, android-manifest

In my android app I have following behaviour. I lock the screen in the app and unlock the screen both by tipping the power button. But after unlocking, I'm directly in my app, although I have the 'slide' screen as lock screen. In other apps on the same phone, I get the 'slide' screen after unlocking. That is also what I want for my app. Is there any Android Manifest option which I have to change, so that I get the slide screen after unlocking?

On phones with older android versions (4.1.2) I got the excepted behaviour.

I'm not sure if this is a coding question or a phone configuration.